# Adding UIScrollView To CCSprite

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone

I want to add a UIScrollView To CCSprite because i want to manage the z value and scroll view is on top always.

I have implemented that by adding to `[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]` but as you know it goes all over the top and I don't want that. please help me out If somebody knows how to do that.

Comment: could you explain a bit better what you are trying to do? an example might help. also, why are you doing that? thanks.

Comment: this is a crazy idea and it's impossible. you can't add uiview to a ccnode. you'll need to implement the scrollview yourself or google for CCScrollView. But if you ask me i'd say you should forget about it

Comment: Not a crazy idea (I've read far worse) but still impossible. All cocos2d nodes are contained within the cocos2d view. You can only add other views in front of or (with some code changes) behind the cocos2d view. This is why CCScrollView is so popular.

Comment: I have an objective c code working fine for scrolling part, but in this case I am implementing a global chat window in my game play So, as a new message pops i have to scroll it automatically which is difficult task for me, thats why i am trying to use UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   try this code (cocos2dx)

CCSprite *sprite;
ScrollView= CCScrollView::create(CCSizeMake(mWidth,mHeight));
ScrollView->setDirection(kCCScrollViewDirectionVertical);

CCLayer* messageLayer = CCLayer::create();
messageLayer->addChild(sprite,1);

messageLayer->setContentSize(CCSizeMake(mWidth, maxContentHeight));
float offsetY = mHeight - messageLayer->boundingBox().size.height;
ScrollView->setContainer(messageLayer);
ScrollView->setContentOffset(ccp(0, offsetY));

ScrollView->updateInset();
ScrollView->setPosition(ccp(0,mHeight/6));
this->addChild(ScrollView);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but sorry karthik I am not looking for that solution.